# Is deleting a cookie in PHP with secure and httponly options worth it?

Tags: php, cookies

Just a question for general knowledge, is deleting a cookie with PHP using just a regular call the same as using it with the secure and httponly set to true?

```
<?php
setcookie('test', $value, -1, '/');
// or
setcookie('test', $value, -1, '/', 'domain.com', true, true);
```

Edit:
Cookie is created with secure and httponly set to true

```
setcookie('test', $value, time() + 3600, '/', 'domain.com', true, true);
```

Comment: The domain, secure and httponly parameters serve different purposes, please refer to [official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) for further information. (considering if originally you set the cookie without secure as true, but now you delete it thru secure only but your site does not force enforcing https, what can happen in different scenarios ?)

Comment: Because you are going over HTTP, the `httponly` is ignored for matching, and browsers are supposed to ignore `secure` when not sent over HTTPS, so as long as you are HTTPS all the way through it shouldn’t matter. According to [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/245624/86698), however, browsers will reject changes to previously made secure cookies over non-secure channels. Cookie prefixes might also introduce a wrinkle if you use them

Comment: The cookie is created with `secure` and `httponly` set to true. I'm just wondering if it will cause any problems with the unsetting of the cookie if I just use a regular unset, with nothing after the `path`

Comment: from what I understand, `httponly` just doesn't allow the use of the cookie through javascript, which I don't really need in my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you have confirmed that `the cookie is created with secure and httponly set to true.`.

In that case if you just use a regular unset, with nothing after the path, the effect will be **the same**

The reasons are

1. without setting the domain, browsers will automatically consider the cookie host-only (i.e. the request's host must exactly match the domain of the cookie), in your case if should be fine if your scripts (set / amend / delete) are triggered in the same host/domain
2. without setting secure, then the cookie will be set in either HTTP and/or HTTPS, so in your case should be fine because your aim is to delete the cookie
3. without setting http only, then it should be fine because you have already confirmed that you do not set / use the cookie thru other ways (such as JS)